# I get an error when I try to play a sound file

Tags: audio, media, clip

I have the following code that I copied from the package playsound because I would like to ask you what is the problem:

```
public class Playsound extends JFrame {

    public Playsound() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("waterdrop.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Playsound();
    }
}
```

But when I try to run it, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:207)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:841)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:178)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1147)
    at playsound.Playsound.<init>(Playsound.java:18)
    at playsound.Playsound.main(Playsound.java:32)
```

It dies at this row:

```
 AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

I have this setup in the folder [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQd40.jpg)

So I would like to ask that why is it not working? Maybe it is me, maybe it is not but it does not work and it is not nice.

Comment: your file is in a wrong folder . put it in src

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JavaFX so I removed the tag.